# How to uninstall MS silverlight developer package?

Tags: windows-7, silverlight

I have Win 7 Enterprise (32 bit) and Visual Studio 2010 ultimate. I installed Silverlight SDK 4.

Now i want to uninstall the update "Microsoft Silverlight Developer Package 4.0" which is visible under updates. But there is no uninstall option for the same. Is there any way i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to first uninstall Silverlight itself.

**Edit**: Try maybe uninstalling using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).
It also creates a system restore point, to use if things go wrong.
You'll surely need to reinstall Silverlight afterward.

Comment: I tried that... but this update won't go.. :(

Comment: @user9695: See my edit.